# NSDictionary - how return the Key as a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I have a plist like this:

```
<dict>
<key>New item</key>
<dict>
    <key>document</key>
    <string>driving licence</string>
    <key>Overview</key>
    <string>a driving licence is required.......</string>
</dict>
```

if I want to get the object I would write something like this:

```
 myString = [somedictionary objectForKey:@"Overview"];
```

what about if I want to get "overview" from my plist???
I Hope it's clear..... Please do not give negative vote.... I'm still learning!;-)

EDITED VERSION:

Better to be more specific:

i have this code

```
 for (NSDictionary *playDictionary in playDictionariesArray) {
        Play *play = [[Play alloc] init];
        play.name = [playDictionary objectForKey:@"playName"];
```

which is the Apple sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

In this sample the string play return the name of the play in the header section but I want
to modify it and get the "Key" in the header (in this case would be "PlayName).

THANKS TO EVERYBODY: THIS IS HOW I FIXED IT:

```
 NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [anArray addObject:@"Overview"];
    [anArray addObject:@"pre-requirements"];
    [anArray addObject:@"where"];
    [anArray addObject:@"what"];


    //Use a for each loop to iterate through the array
    for (NSString *s in anArray) {

            Play *play = [[Play alloc] init];
            play.name = s;
```

Comment: I mean the Key itself not the value for that key....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get an array of all the keys in the dictionary using `[dict allKeys]`.  You can get an array of all keys whose value is a specific object using `[dict allKeysForObject:object]`.  You can process the keys one-by-one in a loop like this:

```
for (NSString *key in dict) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So... do `[[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]` I guess.  Do you understand that a dictionary can have many keys, and there is no defined order for the keys?  In Apple's example, that dictionary has two keys, "playName" and "quotations".  How do you know which one you want?

Comment: I think i'm getting closer. What I want to do is use that expandable cell for my project. The table will show some details and the header (in the apple project "playName") in my case should be something like: "overview", "where", "What", "how"instead of the name of 3 plays. I guess I don't have to use a dictionary  to do that but I was trying to use the code without major change.

Comment: ....probably an array with 4 objects would work as well. something like NSArray *anArray = [NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"overview",@"where",@"what",@"how", nil]; but then i'm not able to set play.name as I want...

Answer (score 3):

try this and if it works let me know..

```
NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString* key in dictionary) {

    [result addObject:key];
    // write to a dictionary instead of an array
    // if you want to keep the keys too.

}
return result;
```

Comment: Or just `[dictionary allKeys]`.

Comment: @rob Experience is the teacher of all things. -"Julius Ceaser"

Comment: if I use [dictionary allKeys] i get the following error : incompatible pointer types passing 'NSArray' to parameter of type 'NSString'

Comment: you are not using it right then.. try rob's approach it is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get the key for a given object, you may try the method:

```
- (NSArray *)allKeysForObject:(id)anObject
```

Using it like this:

```
myString = [[myDict allKeysForObject:@"a driving licence is required......."] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Just notice that it returns an NSArray, because you can have more than one key for the specified object.